# Android: which parts in the XML files cause an InflateException on long click of the view

Tags: android

Here's the screen of what I am struggling with.

[image]

The white box in the centre of the screen are two EditTexts. There is no problem when simply clicking the EditText, but If I long-click them, the app quits with an error, leaving the following exception in the log.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3474)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2654)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3398)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3398)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:4466)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:4896)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:5361)
                                                       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1001)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:10113)
                                                       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:19242)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3474) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2654) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3398) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3398) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:4466) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:4896) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:5361) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1001) 
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:10113) 
                                                       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:19242) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=659
                                                       at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
                                                       at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:459)
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:721)
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:125)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1509)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:908)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3474) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2654) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3398) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3398) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:4466) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:4896) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:5361) 
                                                       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1001) 
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:10113) 
                                                       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:19242) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think this is due to some misled attributes on the XML files used in this activity.

Here is the layout that contains two EditTexts.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlLoginBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_box_top"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/etEmail"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_box_bottom"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, each EditText is referring to its respective drawable files, called `login_box_top.xml` and `login_box_bottom.xml`.

The login_box_top.xml file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset android:insetBottom="-2px" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners  android:topLeftRadius="4dip"
                    android:topRightRadius="4dip"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="0dip" />
                <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#E6E6E6" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners  android:topLeftRadius="4dip"
                    android:topRightRadius="4dip"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="0dip" />
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
                <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#E6E6E6" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
</inset>
```

And here is the login_box_bottom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset android:insetTop="-1px" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dip"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="4dip"
                    android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
                    android:topRightRadius="0dip"  />
                <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#E6E6E6" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dip"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="4dip"
                    android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
                    android:topRightRadius="0dip" />
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
                <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#E6E6E6" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
</inset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a very simple issue. I could prevent the exception simply by adding the attribute `android:longClickable="false"` to each EditText.